# How to validate user login through stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to call the method from my code-behind which links to my business access layer and grabs the method from my data access layer. On the click of the login I want to check if the data table returns a row of matching values, and if so redirect the user to my products page. The problem is, my method isn't returning anything so on the click of the button nothing happens. Can anyone point out what I've done wrong?

```
//code behind
private void Login()
{
   //this connects to BA layer
   string username = Convert.ToString(txtUser.Text);
   string password = Convert.ToString(txtPassword.Text);
   new BALlogin().ValidateUser(username, password);
}

//method in my business access layer
class BALlogin
{
   public void ValidateUser(string username, string password) //wasvoid
   {
      new GetUser().GetUserpassword(username, password);            
   }
}

//code in data access layer
public void GetUserpassword(string username, string password)
{
   DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
   SqlCommand cmdvaliduser = new SqlCommand();
   cmdvaliduser.CommandText = "sp_userlogin";
   cmdvaliduser.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmdvaliduser.Connection = TROPSConnection.GetConnection();
   cmdvaliduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", username);
   cmdvaliduser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
   cmdvaliduser.Connection.Open();
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   da.Fill(dt);

   cmdvaliduser.ExecuteNonQuery();
   cmdvaliduser.Connection.Close();
}

protected void loginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      Login();

      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
      {
         Response.Redirect("Products.spx");
      }
   }
   catch
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
   }
}
```

Comment: **NEVER** store passwords in a format that allows you read them back. You **hash** them, and when someone logs in, you hash the attempted password and compare the hashes. And that's just the short version. Really, _never_ write your own authentication code. Search for and lean on the authentication mechanisms already provided by your platform of choice.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set-up the data adapter correctly. 
You are filling your DataTable, dt, based on an empty DataAdapter 
You should use

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdValidUser);
```

But I agree with Joel, you should store the passwords in your database as hashed values.
Then re-write your Getuserpassword() to be called checkUserPassword() and have it return a Boolean whether the user/password was valid or invalid. 
Set-up your stored procedure so that you pass in the username and the password hash, check it in the database, and then return true/false as an OUTPUT variable from the stored procedure.